# Validating Docusign HMAC Key using C#. Every time it is returning false

Tags: docusignapi, hmac

```
//This is how I am calling from controller
var signature = Request.Headers["X-Docusign-Signature-1"]; 
var message = Request.Body; 
StreamReader reader1 = new StreamReader(message); 
string text = reader1.ReadToEnd();

var isValid = docuSignHMACKeyValidation.HashIsValid(text, signature);

// My Methods
public string ComputeHash(string secret, string payload)
  {
  byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secret);
  HMAC hmac = new HMACSHA256(bytes);
  bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload);
  return Convert.ToBase64String(hmac.ComputeHash(bytes));
  }

public bool HashIsValid(string payload, string verify)
  {
  string secret = "secretkey";
  ReadOnlySpan<byte> hashBytes = 
     Convert.FromBase64String(ComputeHash(secret, payload));
  ReadOnlySpan<byte> verifyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(verify);

  return CryptographicOperations.FixedTimeEquals(hashBytes, verifyBytes);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little suspicious of your line

```
  bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload);
```

I'd try it without an encoding conversion.

Also:

- Check that the hmac signature is in **X-Docusign-Signature-1** (check that you only have one hmac secret set in DocuSign.)
- Use your debugger to check each step and compare with the results from a HMAC checking web site such as https://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.html In other words, first check that you can use the online tool to verify the hmac. Then debug your code to determine why your getting a false response.